# firebase callable cloud function is never triggered after changing region?

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am currently migrating (creating new firebase project), from us-central 1 to asia-southeast2. I am using Firestore, Firebase storage and also cloud function.

I have no issue with Firebase Storage and Firestore, I can save the data as expected. because maybe both firestore and firebase storage are in the default location (asia-southeast2).

the problem is in the cloud function. asia-southeast2 doesn't have cloud function. so I deploy my callable cloud functions to asia-EAST2, like this

```
   exports.callableModeratorAddEventToAlgolia = functions.region("asia-east2").https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

         console.log("this log never called")

   )}
```

and in Android, I call it like this

```
private val functions: FirebaseFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()

fun addingEventToAlgolia(selectedEvent: Event): Task<String> {

        // Create the arguments to the callable function.
        val data = hashMapOf(
            "eventID" to selectedEvent.eventID
        )

        return functions
            .getHttpsCallable("callableModeratorAddEventToAlgolia")
            .call(data)
            .continueWith { task ->
                val result = task.result?.data as String
                result
            }
    }
```

I believe I have deployed the function correctly

[image]

the problem is, that function never called !
I am sure the code is executed in Android, but if I see the cloud function log, that `callableModeratorAddEventToAlgolia` function is never triggered.

I have another function, which is a firestore trigger. and it works well, no issue even though I also deploy it in asia-east2. but I don't know why it doesn't work for callable cloud function

am I missing something ?

because previously, when all firestore, firebase storage and cloud function are all in us-central1. all is good. but when cloud function is not in the same region, I don't know why it is never called.

Answer (score 1):

I think I find the solution, i have to instantiate the callable function object like this

```
val functions: FirebaseFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance("asia-east2")
```